# Reuse virtual machines from Intel laptop on AMD laptop?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

I have Windows, Linux and some other virtual machines (some of them are on VMWare Player, some are on VirtualBox) on my old `Intel` laptop.

Is it possible to just move theirs disks images on my new `AMD` laptop and use them there as is? Or do I have to install these machines from scratch?

Comment: It should be possible to just move and import. Make sure to adjust assigned resources if such adjustment is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUs in desktop computers are generally compatible, because they are all implementations of the same x86_64 architecture. Your VMs will probably detect that the CPU has changed, because VMWare and VirtualBox expose CPU name to the guest, but that shouldn't affect anything.

Some software may take advantage from specific x86_64 extensions, which differ between CPUs. That shouldn't be a problem though, unless you're using specialized builds for specific instruction sets, which is unlikely. Most programs are built to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can generally just take the Virtual Machine folder and put it on the new machine and virtual machines will work.

For the VMware machines, if they were 32-bit machines, they will still work. If you have 64-bit machines, you need to ensure Hardware Virtualization is enabled on the new machine. This is true of any Virtual Machine app.

Again for VMware, when a machine is first built, it includes a Hardware Compatibility setting. It does not always need to change when upgrading the VMware app to a newer version or when changing the physical machine to a new machine.

If you need to (or even to see if the machine works better), you can change the Hardware Compatibility level to a newer level. The machine needs to be OFF and you can change the compatibility level in the machine settings.

I have virtual machines here on this laptop that were created with VMware 1 or 2 on a Windows NT Workstation machine, so you definitely can move virtual machines to new hardware.

Here is a screen shot of the Hardware Compatibility settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This being a new computer it should have the virtualization feature of
[AMD virtualization (AMD-V)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_(AMD-V))
that is necessary to emulate different CPU architecture, in case you intend
running 32-bit VMs on a 64-bit host.

In case of a problem, verify that all hardware virtualization options are
enabled in the BIOS.